# ¿Porque node_modules/@angular/material/material"' no tiene miembro exportado 'MaterialModule'?

Tags: angular

Estoy tratando de comenzar con Angular pero realmente tengo problemas para lanzar ng serve --open pero encontro problemas :

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Documents/Coursera/Angular/conFusion3$ ng serve --open
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
 10% building modules 7/12 modules 5 active .../webpack/hot nonrecursive /^\.\/log$/webpack: wait until bundle finished: /
Date: 2018-04-26T16:46:42.755Z                                                       
Hash: a56ffd9f64acb51cc7ff
Time: 6370ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 3.85 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 2.91 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 577 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 42.2 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 852 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(5,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Documents/Coursera/Angular/conFusion3/node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MaterialModule'.
```

Las únicas respuestas que encontré estaban hablabando sobre el intercambio de "Mat" a "Md" en las importaciones de [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46633867/error-angular-material-material-has-no-exported-member-mdbuttonmodule?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) y [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7692), pero que parecen no estar relacionadas en lo que respecta a mi app.component.ts, son:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({

selector: 'app-root',

templateUrl: './app.component.html',

styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']

})

export class AppComponent {

title = 'app';

}
```

Todo mi código está [en BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/AntoineCompagnie/confusion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te indico lo que tienes que hacer para usar `Angular Material 5.2.5` en tu proyecto.

**1**. Crear un modulo para material donde importaremos de manera individual y creamos el archivo con el nombre `angular-material.module.ts`, lo puedes guardar creando las carpetas en la ruta `"src/app/shared/angular-material"`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }   from '@angular/common';
import {DateAdapter, MatRippleModule, MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material';
import {
  MatAutocompleteModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatButtonToggleModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatChipsModule,
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatExpansionModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatGridListModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatPaginatorModule,
  MatProgressBarModule,
  MatProgressSpinnerModule,
  MatRadioModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatSliderModule,
  MatSlideToggleModule,
  MatSnackBarModule,
  MatSortModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatTabsModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatTooltipModule,
  MatStepperModule,
  MatNativeDateModule,
  MAT_DATE_FORMATS
} from '@angular/material';
import {dateAdapterOta, MY_DATE_FORMATS } from './../adapters/dateAdapterOta';

@NgModule({
      exports: [
        MatAutocompleteModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatButtonToggleModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatChipsModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatExpansionModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatGridListModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatPaginatorModule,
        MatProgressBarModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatRadioModule,
        MatRippleModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatSlideToggleModule,
        MatSliderModule,
        MatSnackBarModule,
        MatSortModule,
        MatStepperModule,
        MatTabsModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        MatNativeDateModule
      ],
      providers:[
        {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: dateAdapterOta},
        {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_DATE_FORMATS}
      ]
})
export class AngularMaterialModule {}
```

**2**. Entrar el archivo `app.module.ts` e importamos el modulo de material

`import { AngularMaterialModule } from './shared/angular-material/angular-material.module';`

```
//añades el modulo de material
import: [
AngularMaterialModule,
]
```

Con eso seria suficiente para que puedas usar los componentes de material en tu proyecto

Answer (score 0):

En la versión de angular material que utilizas se importan los módulos de manera individual.Ej : MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule.

Para tener una mejor idea podes ver la documentación de [angular material](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-3-import-the-component-modules)

Comment: Si, pienso que est es lo que hicé siguiendo las [instrucciones del curso sobre la configuración de una aplicación angular](https://www.coursera.org/learn/angular/supplement/uokSs/exercise-instructions-configuring-your-angular-application). He actualizado el repositorio

Comment: En versiones anteriores de la que estás utilizando se importaba sólo MaterialModule, pero en las ultimas versiones ésto cambio.